# get curl work with Content-Disposition of the response header after sending $_POST request

Tags: php, curl, content-disposition

Ok, to understand the problem, first please visit

```
http://unblockproxy.nu/
```

Try to surf any website, let's say (http://www.example.com/samplepage.html) put it in the field then click "unblock" button

After sending the $_POST request, the site should redirect you to something like:

```
http://unblockproxy.nu/index.php?x=Mfv0KjYRb3J3JO50MgBNbplFn2sTMoqPUIu1Unqn0bqdUoq5VbA9OnO8%3D
```

Response Headers of the browser is like:

```
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 12:49:30 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.15
  x-powered-by: PHP/5.3.3
  Location: http://unblockproxy.nu/index.php?x=Mfv0KjYRb3J3JO50MgBNbplFn2sTMoqPUIu1Unqn0bqdUoq5VbA9OnO8%3D
  Cache-Control: max-age=600, private, must-revalidate
  Expires: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 12:59:30 GMT
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 12:49:34 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.15
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
  Content-Disposition: inline; filename="samplepage.html"
  Cache-Control: max-age=600, private, must-revalidate
  Expires: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 12:59:34 GMT
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

That's easy, now you got the contents of the surfed page by using this web proxy.

Now, i want to do the same job by using curl

My problem is, i don't know how to let curl deal with Content-Disposition of the response header

Here is some codes to simulate my problem::

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://unblockproxy.nu/index.php');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('x' => 'http://www.example.com/samplepage.html'));

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');

 $string = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 echo $string;
```

This will return the contents of http://unblockproxy.nu/ and that is not what i want (http://www.example.com/samplepage.html which surfed by http://unblockproxy.nu/)

If you want to take a look into the script of this site (2 PHP files only), you can [go here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/)

Thank you.

Comment: From my experiences debugging this, the `Content-disposition` has nothing to do with your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This works for me just fine if I'm understanding your question correctly. I removed a lot of code that did nothing. Turns out, the problems was that you weren't setting the `referer` in the request headers.

Let me start from the beginning. Upon submitting the form via `POST` to view a given website with a proxy, a request is sent to http://unblockproxy.nu/index.php. As you mentioned in your question, `index.php` handles the form submission and generates an [HTTP status code of 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) which essentially just redirects you to another page. Assuming that you send a properly formatted request to `index.php`, you can parse the response headers and get the value of the redirect URL. Follow the code below to get the redirect URL.

```
/**
 * Submit the form via POST
 * @param [site_url] The link to the page that you want to view 
 * eg: http://sitetoget.com/page.html
 * @return A string containing the response headers
*/
function GetRedirect($site_url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://unblockproxy.nu/index.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('x' => $site_url));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

/**
 * Turn a header string into an associative array
 * @param [response] The response headers from the form submission 
 * @return An array containing all of the headers
*/
function GetHeaders($response) {
    $headers = [];
    $text = substr($response, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n"));

    foreach(explode("\r\n", $text) as $i => $line) {
        if($i === 0 || $i == 1) {
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        } else {
            list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);

            if($key != '' && $value != '') {
                $headers[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $headers;
}

// Get the redirect URL
$redirect = GetRedirect('http://lancenewman.me/');
// Parse the response headers
$headers = GetHeaders($redirect);
// Save the redirect URL 
$new_url = $headers['Location'];
```

Now that you have the URL that `index.php` redirects to, send a `cURL` request to it as follows. Strangely enough, almost all of the other request headers that I've tinkered with play no role in determining whether or not this solution works. The reason your code is getting the contents of http://unblockproxy.nu instead of the contents of the given site as viewed by `http://unblockproxy.nu` is because you're not following the redirections correctly and you're not setting the `referer` in request headers. The cookies, content-disposition and all of the other headers seem to play no role in solving this.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://unblockproxy.nu');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$string = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $string;
```

It's important to note that some of the images, CSS and JS on some of the pages might not properly load because some use relative URLs instead of absolute ones. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Cookies appear to not play any role in your problem.

Comment: It's working! thank you very much, HTTP REFERRER is the key, i have tracked the request and response header by using Tamper Data addon and i seen it before, but i never thought it was the problem, i'm using multi_curl for my project, so setting CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER as TRUE will be the better option for me, also there is no any needs to run curl twice, just setting the REFERER and everything will work fine, thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it requires two round-trips to the server to complete the request. Many sites use the method to reduce the number or requests by "bots". The first request creates a cookie (typically for a "session") which must be present in order for the form to be processed.

Perform the curl_exec() twice and see if you get the results you want. The first time the response will send a cookie which curl will save since you have enabled cookies. The second time you should get the results you want.